# LoadLibrary() fails when called from plugin but works in test program

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, 3dsmax

I'm working on a [plugin](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed-max) for Autodesk 3ds Max 2017. As per [Max's documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Max-Developer-Help/developer/about-the-3ds-max-sdk/sdk-requirements-html.html), the plugin is compiled inside VS 2017 using the VS 2015 toolset against the 10.0.10586.0 Windows SDK.

When the plugin is loaded by 3ds Max, it in turn programmatically loads a number of DLLs using [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya). Until recently, that was working fine on my machine. It's also still working fine on other developers' machines.

What happens now on my machine is that `LoadLibrary()` fails and returns a null handle. The error code is 127, i.e. "The specified procedure could not be found."

I am quite sure that DLLs that the one I'm trying to load to depends on are available on the system. I have triple-checked with both Dependency Walker and its modern incarnation, [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).

In fact, the following program run inside Visual Studio 2017 (also using VS 2015 toolset against the 10.0.10586.0 Windows SDK) is able to load that DLL just fine:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto result = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\path\\to\\appleseed.dll");
}
```

To investigate this problem further, I've turned to [GFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags) which is part of the Debugging Tools for Windows 10.

**Here is the full debugger output emitted when calling `LoadLibrary()`**: https://gist.github.com/dictoon/b3f9f7cb52d2d81078965133d5035a03

I believe (but I'm not 100% sure) that the relevant error from this output is the following:

```
5f4c:54bc @ 131346281 - LdrpReportError - ERROR: Locating export "StackWalkEx" for DLL "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll" failed with status: 0xc0000139.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCC6A9EAA8 (ntdll.dll) in 3dsmax.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
5f4c:54bc @ 131346281 - LdrpGenericExceptionFilter - ERROR: Function LdrpSnapModule raised exception 0xc0000139
    Exception record: .exr 000000000223F030
    Context record: .cxr 000000000223EB40
```

`dbgeng.dll` appears to be Visual Studio's debugger so I thought that maybe the error would only occur when 3ds Max was run inside Visual Studio with the debugger attached but that's not the case: the DLL also fails to load when 3ds Max is launched on its own.

Inspecting `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll` with Dependencies reveals that <s>it does export a `StackWalkEx()` symbol</s>:

**Edit 1**: @RbMm commented that `StackWalkEx()` is actually not exported by `dbgeng.dll` but by `dbghelp.dll` as the screenshot below shows:

[image: Dependencies screenshot showing that dbgeng.dll does export StackWalkEx]

**Edit 2**: With a release build of the DLL I'm trying to load, everything works fine too. Looking at the debugger's output, no attempt is made at loading `dbgeng.dll` or finding `StackWalkEx()`.

**Edit 3**: It appears that the debug version of the library I'm trying to load *does* have a dependency toward `dbgeng.dll`:

[image: Library that fails to load depends on dbgeng.dll]

But a small test DLL written from scratch doesn't!

**Edit 4**: I now suspect that Boost 1.69 (on which the DLL I'm trying to load depends) to which we recently switched (from Boost 1.55) has introduced a dependency on `dbgeng.dll` via its Stacktrace library introduced in Boost 1.65.

Comment: Seems odd that it is finding one from `c:\windows\sytem32\`, perhaps there are newer versions of this DLL, maybe one just for VS2017, or one from Windows SDK.

Comment: You could continue on your test example that works and try to call `StackWalkEx`  dynamicly via GetProcAddr: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress. Besides that, my guess is that you could have different versions of the dll lying around or some kind of versioning issue.

Comment: I do have a bunch of `dbgeng.dll` files on my system: https://gist.github.com/dictoon/dc0c6bd16f2a181b7873258f4e35e39c

Comment: `StackWalkEx` is exported by `DbgHelp.dll`, but in log somebody try found it in `dbgeng.dll`. post **full** log

Comment: I just realized that on my screenshot Dependencies seems to indicate that `StackWalkEx` is indeed exported by `dbghelp.dll`, how confusing. When you say "post full log", which log do you have in mind? I've posted everything I had.

Comment: when you set ntdll.ShowSnaps to 0xFFFFFBF or via  GFlags - huge number of debug output will be. need view more lines, before *5f4c:54bc @ 131346281 - LdrpReportError - ERROR: Locating export "StackWalkEx" for DLL "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll" failed with status: 0xc0000139*

Comment: The log I posted to Gist is the full log emitted when `LoadLibrary()` is called. In case you missed it, here's the link again: https://gist.github.com/dictoon/b3f9f7cb52d2d81078965133d5035a03

Comment: LoadLibrary() cannot produce error 127, only GetProcAddress() can do that.  For all we know it is the error checking that has a bug, none is visible in the snippet.  Don't call GetLastError() unless LoadLibrary returns NULL.

Comment: But `LoadLibrary()` returns `nullptr`, that's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an older version of `dbghelp.dll` which ships with 3ds Max and conflicts with the newer version the appleseed.dll has been linked with during the debug build.

The call to the function `StackWalkEx`, which failed, has a dependency on `dbghelp.dll`
[StackWalkEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-stackwalkex)

The solution is to inactivate or replace the older, incompatible version of `dbghelp.dll` inside the Max root directory.

`StackWalkEx` is part of DbgHelp and used by System Services. It may have been updated recently during a Windows update causing the breaking change.